# Auto-indent the whole text file shortcut?

Tags: vim, vi

What's the shortcut for autointenting the whole text file (like .c files or .java files). It should be equivalent to the `tab` in emacs but I couldn't find a correct way to do this online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reindent the whole file can be done with.

```
gg=G
```

`gg` moves to the top of the file.
`=G` reindents from the cursor position to the end of the file.

Comment: How to specify which indentation style to use? I'm trying to indent a matlab file.

Comment: @OneZero The indentation is normally controlled by the filetype and a couple of settings such as `softtabstop, tabstop and shiftwidth`. Its might also be nessesary to have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc.

Comment: This removes an indent, doesn't add one, how is this the accepted answer?
`>G` will add an indent to end of file.

Comment: Nevermind, `=` performs an auto indent.  Still good to know about `>` and `<` though :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @FDinoff's suggestion, you could also use autocmd/au for user-defines filetype indentation settings. Like so-

au FileType c setl sw=8 ts=8 noet (For C);

au FileType python setl sw=4 ts=4 et (for python)

and so on..